# Family of homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\{ \phi_{y}\},\: y \in X$,  a family of homeomorphisms on topological space $X$ ($\phi_{y}: X \rightarrow X$). Suppose $H: X \times X \rightarrow X$ is continuous, $\: H(x, y) = \phi_{y}(x)$. Does $G:X \times X \rightarrow X \times X, \: G(x, y) = (\phi_{y}(x), y)$ have to be a homeomorphism?

I know that this statement will be true if $X$ is a smooth manifold, $\{ \phi_{y}\}$ diffeomorphisms and they smoothly depend on parameter.

My suggestion that statement doesn't hold for general topological space, but I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: Interesting. This hinges on continuity of the pairing $X\times X\to X$, $(x,y)\mapsto\phi_y^{-1}(x)$